# fullcalendar height not considering surrounding container

Tags: html, css, vuejs2, fullcalendar

I have a vue.js project which I am integrating vue-fullcalendar into and I am running into an issue where the `.fc-scroller fc-time-grid-container` height is set beyond the height of the surrounding container.

I borrowed a codepen example from fullcalendar.io to recreate the situation. I structured the App.vue file as close as I could get it to my actual application: https://codesandbox.io/s/p3418kmo7

[image: Slots scrolling off the page forcing the main container to scroll]

[image: Changing the height property here to something smaller like 500px forces the scrollable area to within the bounds of the surrounding container]

When you click "open in a new window" it appears that the height of the scrollable area is being set to a value which isnt considering the fact that its not the only thing on the page. I have tried setting the fullcalendar.io properties `height` and `contentHeight` without any changes to the overall behavior. When you force the height property `<div class="fc-scroller fc-time-grid-container" style="overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: scroll; height: 879px;">` in Chrome's html editor to a value smaller then the main container (in my case 500px works) the scrollable area shrinks and fits inside the main container removing the additional scrollbar.

I am not really sure what to do here, how can you control the computed height of the scrollable area so that your main container isnt overflowing off the page?

Answer (score 2):

So after some debugging I was able to figure out that the properties `contentHeight` & `height` are not respected with passing them into a view specific configuration as I had above. Adding them to the global configuration & setting them to `'auto'` worked out in my case but it would be nice to be able to handle each view independently.

Also wrapping the `<full-calendar>` template with a `<div style='overflow-y: auto; max-height: calc(100vh-150px);">...` was enough to solve my problem. It would be nice if the default aspectRatio calculation took into consideration things like the navbar height.

Here is the demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/mjz32jnoop